# Umbraco 4.11 models and template inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco and MVC - can anyone help with the following?

I have a master template (Root.cshtml) which has templates nested below it. In some of these I want to use custom models, however Root.cshtml needs access to the Umbraco helper.

So the nested pages inherit from Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<*CustomModel*>, whilst Root.cshtml needs to inherit from something more general.

I've tried having my custom models inherit from Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel however I keep being told that either my custom model does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments or, or if I give it one, that 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

What am I doing wrong and how should I accomplish this nesting?

```
namespace CRuMbraco.Web.Models {
public class RegisterModel : RenderModel {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Customer code")]
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm email")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The e-mail and confirmation e-mail do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your model constructors?

Comment: Have added my class definition above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All views that use the master template should `@inherit` from `UmbracoTemplatePage`.

`UmbracoTemplatePage` actually inherits from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<RenderModel>` and has two additional properties `CurrentPage` and `Umbraco`, the latter as you say is an instance of the `UmbracoHelper` class.

I'm fairly sure that you cannot replace this with a custom model because an instance of model is determined by the Umbraco routing.

However, if you wish the views to have a custom model you should child actions instead. These will allow you pass you custom objects into the page independently of the `RenderModel`. If you want something to be available throughout all pages/views regardless of whether they are views, partial views or child actions you could create a global filter that sets data to the Viewbag from the session for example.

There is some documentation here which may help talk you through [the Umbraco MVC basics](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/).

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll use child actions, then.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use a UmbracoViewPage like so:

```
Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<RegisterModel>
```

To do this your custom model will need to extend the RenderModel, like:

```
public class RegisterModel: RenderModel 
{
    public RegisterModel(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture)
        : base(content, culture)
    {
    }
    // my properties here
}
```

You can instantiate you're custom model by hi-jacking the route, see: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/custom-controllers

So, you'll end up with something like:

```
public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        var customUmbracoModel = new RegisterModel(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture);

        // do some extra form stuff here

        return base.Index(customUmbracoModel );
    }
}
```